# Replace element of list at position n by e -Racket

Tags: list, racket

How do i do in Racket a function that replaces the element of a list at the position n by e.

```
(repl-elem '(a b c d e) 2 d)
```

should return `a d c d e`

Comment: In Racket this function is called [`list-set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._list-set%29%29). The only difference is that it uses zero-based indexing, so index 2 would be where the `'c` is.

Comment: How does that work? I can't find any examples of how it really works, i need to understand the mechanics behind this `list-set`

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the element with index 2 in a list with a new element 'A,
one can do the following:

```
#lang racket
(define xs (list 1 2 3 4 5))

(append (take xs 2)
        (list 'A)
        (drop xs (+ 2 1)))
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to turn this into a function.

Comment: As Alex mentioned in a comment, this already exists (in a more efficient way) as [`list-set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._list-set%29%29).

Answer (score 0):

To see "the mechanics behind this list-set" one can use 'named let' recursion:

```
(define (f L n c)
  (let loop ((x 1)
             (ol '()))
    (cond
      [(> x (length L))
       (reverse ol)]
      [(= x n)
       (loop (add1 x) (cons c ol))]
      [else
       (loop (add1 x) (cons (list-ref L (sub1 x)) ol))])))
```

Testing:

```
(f '(a b c d e) 2 'd)
```

Output:

```
'(a d c d e)
```

OP can figure out how it is working.